# How to extract a string between 2 other strings in python?

Tags: python, string

Like if I have a string like `str1 = "IWantToMasterPython"`

If I want to extract `"Py"` from the above string. I write:

```
extractedString = foo("Master","thon")
```

I want to do all this because i am trying to extract lyrics from an html page. The lyrics are written like `<div class = "lyricbox"> ....lyrics goes here....</div>`.

Any suggestions on how can I implement.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The solution is to use a regexp:

```
import re
r = re.compile('Master(.*?)thon')
m = r.search(str1)
if m:
    lyrics = m.group(1)
```

Comment: Nicely answered. Exactly what I wanted to know.
Thanx

Answer (score 11):

BeautifulSoup is the easiest way to do what you want. It can be installed like:

```
sudo easy_install beautifulsoup
```

The sample code to do what you want is:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

doc = ['<div class="lyricbox">Hey You</div>']
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))
print soup.find('div', {'class': 'lyricbox'}).string
```

You can use Python's [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) to grab content from the url directly.  The [Beautiful Soup doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Quick%20Start) is helpful too if you want to do some more parsing.

Comment: This is definitely the correct way to about it for what he says he's using it for.

Comment: Nicely put. Thats what my purpose was.
It really helps.

Answer (score 9):

```
def foo(s, leader, trailer):
  end_of_leader = s.index(leader) + len(leader)
  start_of_trailer = s.index(trailer, end_of_leader)
  return s[end_of_leader:start_of_trailer]
```

this raises ValueError if the leader is not present in string s, or the trailer is not present after that (you have not specified what behavior you want in such anomalous conditions; raising an exception is a pretty natural and Pythonic thing to do, letting the caller handle that with a try/except if it know what to do in such cases).

A RE-based approach is also possible, but I think this pure-string approach is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If you're extracting any data from a html page, I'd strongly suggest using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library. I used it also for extracting data from html and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this if your would like all the occurrences output in a list :

```
import re
str1 = "IWantToMasterPython"

out  = re.compile('Master(.*?)thon', re.DOTALL |  re.IGNORECASE).findall(str1)
if out :
    print out
```